# In Prometheus, why did only the humans evolve from the space jockey/Engineer who drank from the cup and not the alien creatures

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus, origins, evolution

In Prometheus, why did only the humans evolve from the space jockey/Engineer who drank from the cup that contained the alien gene/recipe and not the actual alien creatures they are supposed to create

It is clear from the scene that the Engineer did drink from the same cup/vessel that is supposed to spawn the alien creatures.